# Polyhedral version of sphere eversion

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology, polyhedra

Is there a polyhedral version of sphere eversion (Smale's theorem), where you take a *polyhedron* with triangular faces homeomorphic to the sphere, and *continuously move the vertices* such that *no dihedral angle becomes zero* (that is, no pair adjacent faces ever overlap) and such that it *ends inside-out* of how it started?

If so, how many vertices do we need? A simple argument shows the tetrahedron cannot be everted in that manner. I don't think the octahedron can, either. I imagine this probably needs a large polyhedron to work.

(Alternate question: What if you require that the dihedral angles never leave $(\pi-\epsilon,\pi+\epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon$?)

Comment: I think the cuboctahedron works

Comment: This video shows it briefly: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cdMLLmlS4Dc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apery and Denner showed that the cuboctahedron is the minimum polyhedron that can be everted in the way you describe.

Comment: Must the square faces be further subdivided into triangles, or can they be left as squares?

Comment: Revisiting this, I think the reason this can be done is because the cuboctahedron covers the [tetra-hemi-hexahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahemihexahedron), which is a polyhedral version of the projective plane.

Comment: Further searching suggests that the squares do indeed need to be subdivided into triangles. Orienting the cuboctahedron such that the top and bottom faces are squares: the subdividing edges should form an equator, and skew edges at the poles.